# Facebook App Form Integrating

Tags: php, facebook, forms

I have a simple php mailer script I often use on sites and I am trying to integrate it into a facebook app. The app is running through Heroku as usual and is set up correctly.

The Form however is not working, it goes through all the motions but doesn't actually send the email.

I wonder if anyone can shed any light on this? Essentially its a competition answer form for a facebook page tab app. Should I be using a fb:form or something?

Thanks in advance

Kev

HTML FOR FORM

```
<form action="mailer.php" id="form" method="post" name="form">
<div class="field form-inline">
<label class="contact-info" for="txtName">Name*</label> <input class=
"txt" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
</div>

<div class="field form-inline">
<label class="contact-info" for="txtEmail">Email*</label> <input class=
"txt" id="email" name="email" type="text" value="">
</div><br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<div class="submit">
<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit Form">
</div>
</form>
```

PHP FOR FORM

```
<?php
$name    = $_POST['name'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];

$form_message = "Name: $name \nEmail: $email";

// echo for form completion

$myString = "Thank you for filling out our feedback form.";
echo $myString;

//header( "Location: http://www.google.com");//

mail("kevinhowbrook@me.com", "Email Subject", $form_message, "From: $email" );

?>
```

Comment: It´s in an iframe, so you can use your own form. Please post the relevant code, else it is nearly impossible to tell you what´s wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you can debug (and the echoed text shows up), i am guessing it´s a problem with the mail function itself. If you don´t use it with additional info, any spam filter will block it.

Some pages i found with a quick google search:

http://www.transio.com/content/how-pass-spam-filters-php-mail

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

You can also use a PHP mailer class, like this one:

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: So its nothing to do with facebook blocking it?

Comment: no, facebook does not block this (i am using it daily in my projects), and you can do (almost) anything you want to in the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I take it the iframe has to be https?

Comment: yeah, every canvas app or page app (tab) has to be on a server with SSL